# Как сделать так чтобы запрос воспринимал пробел?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня в БД хранятся 2 записи обе включают в себя пробел. И когда я хочу удалить её с помощью запроса в php он не воспринимает пробел и не удаляет его, как это исправить?

```
                // вывод данных из бд
             <?php $sql = mysqli_query($conn3,"SELECT * FROM `Food`");?>
    <div class="con">
        <?php foreach($sql as $row):?>
            <?php 
                $dish = $row['dish_name'];?>
        <div>
            <h1 class="red" ><?php echo $dish;?></h1> 
            <input type="submit" class="del" name="<?php echo $dish;?>" value="Удалить">
            
            <a class="red_" name="<?php echo $dish;?>" href="Reduct.php">Редактировать</a>
      
        
        </div>
        <?php endforeach;?>

    //сам запрос

             <?php
         if(isset($_POST[$dish])){
           $sql = "DELETE FROM `Food` WHERE dish_name = '$dish'";}
               if($conn3 ->query($sql)=== TRUE){
                 echo 'ez';
               }
             ?>
```

Comment: может разные пробелы?

Comment: обычно таки в таблицах заводят ключи и удаляют, используя значение ключа, а не просто текстовое поле с названием.

Comment: `.. WHERE TRIM(dish_name) = ''`

Comment: Так и сделал в итоге ,teran,пасиб